# How to find the file causing a mysql syntax error

Tags: mysql, syntax

I'm a newbie. I just set up Ubuntu to run on my Chromebook (via Crouton) last week and am currently in the process of setting up several Wordpress sites on localhost. I successfully installed a new Wordpress site yesterday, and I'm able to access the frontend and backend of the site via localhost no problem.

Today I wanted to create another Wordpress site. But when I try to create a new database in mysql using Terminal, I get the following error:

```html
mysql> CREATE DATABASE;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

How do I figure out which file is causing the syntax error? I checked php.ini, which I edited yesterday, but line 1 looks fine.

Comment: You have to _name_ your new database, like `create database MyDB;`. And to answer your question: No _file_ caused the error, you did it yourself, right at the terminal ;-)

Comment: Yes, yes! What a silly mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to use Mysql [CREATE DATABASE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_db.asp) statement

```
CREATE DATABASE my_db;
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I didn't think to check that I was writing the command completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To my belief, you are missing the database name:

```
mysql>CREATE DATABASE database_name;
```